# Basis vector and Conical combination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I need your expertise in understanding the following:

Let $B = \{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a basis vectors such that $\forall_{i \in [n]} v_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Its known that w can be represented as a linear combination of $B$ however what must be shown that $w$ is can also be represented as Conical combination of $B$?

Please advise and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a conical combination?

Comment: In linear combination, the coefficients that will be multiplied by the basis vectors can be any scalar while in conical combination these coefficients are non-negative scalars

Comment: I don't think this is true without further conditions. The vector $-v_i$ is not going to be a conical combination.

Comment: What kind of conditions can we establish on $w$ such that we can ensure conical combination using $B$?